# Error al integrar librerias externas React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Espero anden muy bien!
He tenido un problea con la importación de librerias externas en un proyecto React, espero me puedan orientar para poder resolverlo.

La importación de estas librerias lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera dentro del App.js.

```
   componentDidMount(){
     let scripts = [
         { src: "./assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/popper.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/aos.js" }
     ];

     // Añadir scripts a sitio
     scripts.map(item => {
         const script = document.createElement("script")
         script.src = item.src
         script.async = true
         document.body.appendChild(script);
     })
  }
```

El problema es que al momento de compilar en localhost ocurre el siguiente error. Entiendo que no encuentran las rutas de los archivos por eso da el error. Sin embargo los archivo si lo tengo en esa ruta. (me pasa con todos)

[image: Error al compilar]

Comment: podrías agregar las cdn de la pagina oficial de bootstrap, es mas sencillo y sin escribir ni siquiera una linea de código

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar `script.type = "text/babel"`. También deberías usar `forEach` en lugar de `map` porque `map` espera un valor de retorno.

```
scripts.forEach(item => {
         const script = document.createElement("script");
         script.src = item.src;
         script.async = true;
         script.type = "text/babel";
         document.body.appendChild(script);
     });
```

Comment: Hola milmal! gracias por tu respuesta, si me faltaba cambiar el .map por forEach. Agregué el script.type = "text/babel" y dejó de darme el error, sin embargo los scripts no se cargan en el sitio, y no se porque :/. Me guié de la siguiente solución https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668. Saludos!

Comment: Aquí tienes una [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-voice-nwxes?file=/src/App.js) que funciona. (Mira el console para los scripts) Pero creo que quieres usar [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) en su lugar.